# Onclick of button Expand KendoUI TreeView in Jquery -Its not repatitive question

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, treeview

I have a Kendo UI Treeview as shown in the attachment. I have to expand all tree onclick of a button, I know the code to perform expand, but it doesn't expand complete child nodes, instead what it does is just expand only 1 immediate child, even if it has more than one level depth; we need to keep clicking the Expand button further. How to expand the whole tree on click of a button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KckrL.jpg)
This is My code:

```
$("#expand").on("click", function(){
                    var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
                        treeview.expand(".k-item");
            })
```

Comment: Please post this information

Comment: Although slightly different, this should be what you are looking for: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/nodes/expand-all-nodes-upon-check

Comment: Thanks Carsten for the response, I basically need to expand all the child nodes on click of button like Expand All buton, please help me if you know any soluation